# comparing two std::string consts returned from functions (two json-spirit get_str()s) 1-liner

Tags: c++, validation, constants, string-comparison, json-spirit

I'm using [json-spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented) to parse json for my [ws++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) server.

I'm comparing strings for validation of the signup process, confirmed logins, email, password, etc.

json-spirit's `get_str()` returns `const std::string&`.

I've tried `==`, `compare`, even `strcmp`.  All crash the program with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what():  value type is 0 not 2` when I try to compare the function returns with a "1 liner" (all in the `if` comparison statement).

Can this function be returned using a 1-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here: I think your source `json` is not giving you what you think it's giving you in terms of the type of the value.

I'm not familiar with json-spirit, but your link has this paragraph:

`You obtain the Value's type by calling Value::type(). You can then call the appropriate getter function. Generally, you will know a file's format, so you will know what type the JSON values should have. A std::runtime_error exception is thrown if you try to get a value of the wrong type, for example, if you try to extract a string from a value containing an integer.`

This sounds an awful lot like the error you're seeing. I'm guessing json-spirit thinks your strings aren't strings at all. When you try to call `get_str()` on something that's not a string (whatever is defined as type "0") it's throwing an exception.

EDIT: poking around in [json-spirit's source](https://github.com/sirikata/json-spirit/blob/master/include/json_spirit/value.h), type "0" is NULL_TYPE

Comment: i definitely messed up how I was passing the `mObject`, but I think I've corrected it, and `==` and `compare` don't work.  thanks for that catch!  i'm going to test with separate `std::string` variables, and see what happens...